# A C (***void type) to go, why the address is not equal

Tags: go, pointers, cgo

I take a test:
first i have a C func
Variable Initialization:
numRows, numCols, and numDeps are initialized with values 3, 5, and 2 respectively.
These variables represent the dimensions of the 3D array.
Memory Allocation:
Memory is allocated for the array of pointers (features) representing the rows.
For each row, memory is allocated for an array of pointers (features[i]).
For each element in the 2D array, memory is allocated for an array of doubles (features[i][j]).
The memory for each double in the 3D array (features[i][j][k]) is initialized with the value of k.
Printing Addresses:
Nested loops iterate through each element in the 3D array.
The address of each element (features[i][j][k]) is printed using %p format specifier.
Returning the Result:
The address of the entire 3D array (features) is printed.
The 3D array is cast to void*** and returned.

```c
void*** data13feature() {
    int numRows = 3;  // Number of rows
    int numCols = 5;  // Number of columns
    int numDeps = 2;

    // Allocate memory for the array of pointers (rows)
    double*** features = (double***)malloc(numRows * sizeof(double**));

    // Allocate memory for each row (array of doubles)
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        features[i] = (double**)malloc(numCols * sizeof(double*));
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j) {
            features[i][j] = (double*)malloc(numDeps * sizeof(double));
            for (int k = 0; k < numDeps; ++k) {
                features[i][j][k] = k;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the addresses of the array elements
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < numDeps; ++k) {
                printf("%p ", (void*)&features[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return (void***)features;
}
```

then i use cgo to run the func

```golang
func Data2featureWrapper4() {
    result := C.data13feature()
    typeOfMyVar := reflect.TypeOf(result)
    fmt.Printf("typeOfMyVar: %v\n", typeOfMyVar)
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", *result)
}
```

the result is

```
0x33289c0 0x33289c8 
0x33289e0 0x33289e8 
0x3328a00 0x3328a08 
0x3328a20 0x3328a28 
0x3328a40 0x3328a48 

0x3328a90 0x3328a98 
0x3328ab0 0x3328ab8 
0x3328ad0 0x3328ad8 
0x3328af0 0x3328af8 
0x3328b10 0x3328b18 

0x3328b60 0x3328b68 
0x3328b80 0x3328b88 
0x3328ba0 0x3328ba8 
0x3328bc0 0x3328bc8 
0x3328be0 0x3328be8 

typeOfMyVar: **unsafe.Pointer
0x3328990
```

why the start of features[0][0][0] is not equal 0x3328990

i test the **void and *void i find it is equal. where wrong?
Shouldn't the start position of the 3D pointer be the address of the [0][0][0] element? If I want to reverse parse this 3D array using go, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're only dereferencing result once, when you should be dereferencing it twice. We can see that this is a problem by looking at the type of the two things we're comparing:

```
&features[i][j][k]
```

The above is a `double*`. In the go code you had:

```golang
*result
```

Which is an `*unsafe.Pointer` (technically a double pointer, unsafe.Pointer counts as a pointer!). If you think about the structure of what you're allocating, this makes sense:

[rows] => [cols] => [deps]

What you get when you dereference result once is the pointer to the column data. If you dereference it once more you'll get what you want, the array data.

PS, a more efficient way to allocate large blocks of memeory where the shape remains constant is to do it all in one big block. I may rewrite your C code as:

```
void* data13feature() {
    int numRows = 3;  // Number of rows
    int numCols = 5;  // Number of columns
    int numDeps = 2;

    // Allocate memory for the array of pointers (rows)
    double* features = (double*)malloc(numRows * numCols * numDeps * sizeof(double));

    // Print the addresses of the array elements
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < numDeps; ++k) {
                printf("%p ", (void*)&features[(i*numCols) + (j * numDeps) + k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return (void*)features;
}
```

Now you'll also notice that the data is all contiguous in memory, making it cache friendly (especially for large sizes) and only requires a single malloc/free.